# Can't Make a file to current dir says "readonly filesystem" on bash script mac

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

i'm trying to make a file that is `.env` file from bash script, but found error that says `line 7: /.env: Read-only file system`. I can make a file in other dir, but when I tried to make a file in current bash script dir the problem occur.

Here's my bash script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ip=$(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
echo $SCRIPT_DIR
echo "REACT_APP_BASE_API=https://$ip:3030/api/\nCOOKIE_TOKEN_KEY=\nREACT_APP_WEB_SOCKET_URL=wss://$ip:3030/one2one" > $dir/.env

cat .env
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: The basic problem is that you set the variable `SCRIPT_DIR` but then reference `dir` instead. I would strongly recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), as it will point out this and some other potential problems.

Comment: Yes, you use the `dir` variable but haven’t given it anything.  Just glancing at your code, the question is, “what is `dir`?”

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks I didn't realize i'm writing different var name there

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I go to the current dir first before write the file, and it fix the problem.

My code changed to this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ip=$(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

cd $SCRIPT_DIR

echo "REACT_APP_BASE_API=https://$ip:3030/api/\nCOOKIE_TOKEN_KEY=\nREACT_APP_WEB_SOCKET_URL=wss://$ip:3030/one2one" > .env
```